# Getting Image in Python Without Modules And Python Details

Tags: python-3.x, image

1)I am new to programming and was wondering how one would go about getting an image from a file location to the screen in python without having to import any modules (if this is possible).

2)Maybe what I am really asking is for a tutorial or an advance tutorial on python, computer programming in general, or maybe some tutorials in computer science.  Some direction and guidance on where I can answer all of my question about what is part of the python programming language and what is made for quick and easy coding would be appreciated. (An example question of what I would liked answered is "can I make every built in and downloadable python module using just python code or is lower level coding needed and if no lower level coding is needed what is the python code to make these really cool modules"?)

(I took a beginners class in python and have become extremely fond of computers ever since.  Now I have been teaching myself C++ and Java and just want to understand the details behind these languages and want to understand how computer scientist and software engineers create the things they do so sorry if I ask a lot of questions.)

Answer (score 0):

1) Of course it's not possible. You can open the image file, but to render it on the screen you need some sort of graphical toolkit, and you need to import modules to do that.

In fact, only the absolutely most common things are, as it's called, "built in" in Python. You need to import a lot in Python, and there is no reason for you not to do this, so the question in itself doesn't make sense.

2) There are tons of tutorials that do what you want. One of the most popular ones are "[Learn Python the Hard Way](http://learnpythonthehardway.org/)". I've looked at it briefly and it seems good.

Comment: @user2544603: Here on stackoverflow we vote up and accept the answer as a way of saying thanks. :-)